# Angular.js first issue

Tags: angularjs

I am following a tutorial but stuck on one issue. I don't know what I am missing here.

```
    //script.js
    var MainController = function($scope)
    {
      $scope.message = "Hello!!!!";
    };

<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.4" data-semver="1.3.4" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

Problem is -
The message is not binding.

Comment: Turn your code into a single file chunk and re post your question. (with the code)

Comment: Try this: change `<html ng-app>` to `<html ng-app="app">` and your javascript to `angular.module("app", [])
.controller("MainController", function() {});`.

Comment: your code will work with Angular 1.0.7, I guess things changed a bit , have a look at http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-controller-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your module first, then add the controller to the module, specify both the app and controller in your HTML portion.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.4" data-semver="1.3.4" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script>
     var app = angular.module('app',[]);
      var MainController1 = function($scope)
      {
        $scope.message = "Hello!!!!";
      };
      app.controller("MainController1", MainController1);

    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController1">
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```